# Can JAX-B include an XML-valued attribute verbatim?

Tags: xml, jaxb, jax-ws

I have an object which is the return value for a web service method. One of its properties contains an XML document. Ideally, I'd like to have JAX-B include that XML document verbatim in the web service response, rather than escaping everything or having to unmarshal it just to allow the webservice mapping to marshal it again immediately.

Can this be done via annotations or a custom binding definition?

**EDIT:**
The reason I want to do this is that the XML document is retrieved from an Oracle DB (column type XmlType), and I generally want to avoid unnecessary parsing/formatting steps in getting it out to the webservice client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll have to convert the XML string into a `org.w3c.dom.Element` object first, add that to your model, and annotate it with [`@XmlAnyElement`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAnyElement.html). JAXB will then serialize that as verbatim XML (schema validation not withstanding).

Comment: The reason for wanting this is that the property is retrieved from an Oracle XmlType column via JPA. Is there a way to get JPA to directly translate from such a column to a property of type org.w3c.dom.Element?

Comment: @Michael: Not that I'm aware of, no. How about doing the String-to-DOM conversion inside a method in your model, and annotate the method instead of the field?